# Android, ways to pick an image from a gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I've found there are two different ways (at least):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                  Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
                        R.id.select_image_request);
```

and

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent().setType("image/*")
                                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE),
                        R.id.select_image_request);
```

Is there any difference? Are there any others ways to do the same with an Intent?